# Dynamically change container when clicking radiobutton

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, radio-button

I would like to change dynamically container after clicking on a radiobutton. I know I can do it easily using a ng-model and value. 
Here is a JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/vDTRp/2/
It works fine when you have a small container or just some text. But how can I do that with a huge container stored in a scope ?

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.value[0]='<div>big container when clicking radiobutton 1</div>'
    $scope.value[1]='<div>big container when clicking radiobutton 2</div>'
    $scope.value[2]='<div>big container when clicking radiobutton 3</div>'
}
```

$scope.value[0] got the container of my radiobutton 1, $scope.value[1] got the container of my radiobutton 2 and $scope.value[2] got the container of my radiobutton 3.

What should the HTML be to do that dynamically ? (By 'dynamically' I mean clicking on a radiobutton changes the container as the example shown in the jsfiddle.)

Thank you a lot !

Comment: what is the problem with huge containers? you didn't specified.

Comment: I would use ng-switch and keep template logic in templates and not putting it in js code.

Comment: That's a good idea, I didn't know this directive ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.number = '0';
    $scope.value = [];
   $scope.value[0]='<div>big container when clicking radiobutton 1</div>';
    $scope.value[1]='<div>big container when clicking radiobutton 2</div>';
    $scope.value[2]='<div>big container when clicking radiobutton 3</div>';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="radio" ng-model="number" value="0">
<input type="radio" ng-model="number" value="1">
<input type="radio" ng-model="number" value="2">    
<hr> 
{{value[number]}}
</div>
</div>
```

You can do with hide show container on selected radioButton like this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="number" value="0">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="number" value="1">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="number" value="2">    
    <hr> 
    {{value[number]}}
    <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="value[number]"></div> <--if you want bind html than use ng-bind-html-unsafe
</div>
```

And change your controller like this

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.number = '0';
    $scope.value = [];
    $scope.value[0]='<div>big container when clicking radiobutton 1</div>'
    $scope.value[1]='<div>big container when clicking radiobutton 2</div>'
    $scope.value[2]='<div>big container when clicking radiobutton 3</div>'
    $scope.$watch('value', function(value) {
       console.log(value);
    });
}
```